# Delphi TIdTCPClient slow on connect

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have a delphi code that connects to a server using TIdTCPClient.
The server is an advanced ARM microcontroler, the network is a local network (with one switch). 
When the software runs under delphi, TIdTCPClient.Connect runs fast, but when the software runs as a standalone EXE, the connection time is 3s !
For a local connection, this seems very long.
I'm using TIdTCPClient.Connect in a dedicated thread.
Any idea to overcome this is welcome.

Code, cannot be simplier than that:

```
FClient    : TIdTCPClient;
...
FClient    :=TIdTCPClient.Create();
FClient.ConnectTimeout:=5000;
FClient.Port          :=PORT_TCP;
FClient.Host          :='192.178.1.17'

...
FClient.Connect;

...
```

Comment: You need to show some code...

Comment: Are you connecting to an IP address or a hostname?  If the latter, there may be a network delay in the DNS lookup to find the hostname's IP address, and that delay is not included in Indy's `ConnectTimeout` handling. Also, `Connect()` creates its own internal thread to establish the connection, there may be OS delays in thread creation/run/destruction.

Comment: Using an IP, like 192.168.1.17, no DNS.

Comment: This sounds to me like it could be a number of things.
Without the code and server info it will be hard to narrow down.

1. You have intrusive virus scanning software that for every connection from a new exe will run a little check, this may take a while. See how repeatable this 3 second delay is, try it on a different computer or with scanner turned off.

2. You are doing something wrong in code like calling stuff twice where you shouldn't and the connections fight, or some parameters are off, try log what the server is seeing and try 'Wireshark' for inspecting the raw TCP packages.

Comment: Same behavior with a different PC.
Wireshark is a good idea to see what is going on, indeed.